# How to integrate dpdk with openstack installed via packstack?

Tags: openvswitch

My Goal is to run `openstack using packstack for ovs`. Facing ovs-dpdk start issues in ovs startup in various format.

```
Linux: 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
OVS: ovs-vswitchd (Open vSwitch) 2.9.0 DPDK 17.11.0 
DPDK: dpdk-devel-18.11.8-1.el7_8.x86_64
```

Did anyone tried or give pointer how we can integrate ovs and dpdk.

Comment: Is you OVS based on Kernel or DPDK-ovs?

Comment: [root@  ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i openvswitch
openvswitch-selinux-extra-policy-1.0-5.el7fdp.noarch
python-openvswitch-2.9.0-56.el7fdp.noarch
openstack-neutron-openvswitch-12.0.3-5.el7ost.noarch
openvswitch-2.9.0-56.el7fdp.x86_64
[root@  ~]# ovs-vswitchd --version
ovs-vswitchd (Open vSwitch) 2.9.0
DPDK 17.11.0
[root@  ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i dpdk
dpdk-18.11.8-1.el7_8.x86_64
dpdk-tools-18.11.8-1.el7_8.x86_64
dpdk-devel-18.11.8-1.el7_8.x86_64
dpdk-doc-18.11.8-1.el7_8.noarch
[root@  ~]# uname -r
3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
[root@  ~]#

Comment: OVS comes from openstack deployment. DPDK rpms I have manually installed after openstack deployment.

Comment: I am not clear with the information you have shared, OVS build with DPDK support can be activated with `datapath_types=netdev` where interfaces are `iface_types=[dpdkvhostuser0,dpdk0]` etc. In neutron something like `[OVS] datapath_type=netdev`. So are you using OVS with DPDK or Kernel? because you are asking about `linking DPDk with OVS`

Comment: [root@dsp-6 ~]# ovs-vsctl list Open_vSwitch
_uuid               : 9ca7b947-d067-4446-9c15-171ec5416ffb
bridges             : [5f6c25d1-9394-4221-b6ea-aeaed1623434, d55675eb-0944-4f5f-a4ef-70ef18140488, d5af4568-1687-4a5e-8a46-c55555687090, e6348b84-c0fc-41ad-9fa3-9a5f809a52b1]
cur_cfg             : 652
datapath_types      : [netdev, system]
db_version          : "7.15.1"
external_ids        : {hostname="dsp-6", rundir="/var/run/openvswitch", system-id="ee0cafac-8e6a-4403-9ae4-02c1d873363d"}

Comment: other_config        : {dpdk-init="true", dpdk-lcore-mask="101010101010101", pmd-cpu-mask="202020202020202"}
 This are the argument i used in other configs

Comment: You current OVS has the right settings for DPDK-OVS. So your question should be I am facing error in starting DPDK-OVS. Can you share the error log in the question for analysis

Comment: expected  is dpdk_initialized    : true
dpdk_version        : "DPDK 18.11.7" for the   "ovs-vsctl list Open_vSwitch" command is my expection correct

Comment: Each time I get different error some of them are 1) Sep 18 12:51:19 dsp-6 ovs-vswitchd[36988]: ovs|00003|daemon_unix|EMER|/var/run/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.pid: pidfile check failed (Permission denied), aborting
Sep 18 12:51:19 dsp-6 ovs-ctl[36953]: Starting ovs-vswitchd ovs-vswitchd: /var/run/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.pid: pidfile check failed (Permission denied), aborting
 I have tried changing the file permission to 777  aslo

Comment: are you following `https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/v2.5.0/INSTALL.DPDK.md` or something similar to this?

Comment: Some times i get this error also. Sep 18 12:59:28 dsp-6 ovs-vswitchd[39418]: ovs|00017|dpdk|ERR|EAL: Not enough memory available on socket 0! Requested: 1024MB, available: 0MB
Sep 18 12:59:28 dsp-6 ovs-vswitchd[39418]: ovs|00018|dpdk|ERR|EAL: Cannot init memory
Sep 18 12:59:28 dsp-6 ovs-ctl[39383]: Starting ovs-vswitchd EAL: FATAL: Cannot init memory
Sep 18 12:59:28 dsp-6 ovs-ctl[39383]: ovs-vswitchd: Cannot init EAL (End of file)
Sep 18 12:59:28 dsp-6 ovs-vswitchd[39417]: ovs|00002|daemon_unix|ERR|fork child died before signaling startup (killed (Aborted))

Comment: this looks trivial error with DPDK EAl for not having root permission or access to free hugepages. I humbly request to follow any DPDK-OVS guide and ensure it can run without issues first.

Comment: That was my question already I tried two times. One  following  similar steps mention in the link https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/v2.5.0/INSTALL.DPDK.md. Next I have followed  Just by installing openvswitch and dpdk rpm  [root@dsp-6 ~]# rpm -qa | grep openvswitch
openvswitch-selinux-extra-policy-1.0-5.el7fdp.noarch
python-openvswitch-2.9.0-56.el7fdp.noarch
openstack-neutron-openvswitch-12.0.3-5.el7ost.noarch
openvswitch-2.9.0-56.el7fdp.x86_64
[root@dsp-6 ~]# rpm -qa | grep dpdk
dpdk-18.11.8-1.el7_8.x86_64
dpdk-tools-18.11.8-1.el7_8.x86_64
dpdk-devel-18.11.8-1.el7_8.x86_64

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I will submit an edit with relevant details soon. Please share the error logs to it

Comment: deepak, did you get a chance to capture the error logs? Can you make yourself available  on chat or skype?

Comment: I was able to resolve  the issue. But adding  /usr/lib/systemd/system/ovs-vswitchd.service  in ExecStartPre=-/root/bind.sh  cat /root/bind.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
dpdk-devbind  --bind=vfio-pci 12:00.0
# cat /etc/modules-load.d/vfio-pci.conf
vfio-pci
#

Comment: Thanks for you help vipin.  Still i have one issue. System consumes  more memory eventhough system has 128GB ram available.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=rhel/root rd.lvm.lv=rhel/swap rhgb quiet default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=32 iommu=pt intel_iommu=on isolcpus=1-7,9-15,17-23,25-31,33-39,41-47,49-55,57-63"
After configuring  32 gb. i have only 35 GB memory left out.# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            125          88          35           0           1          35
Swap:             3           0           3
#  hence not able to create more than 2 vms

Comment: #  cat /sys/devices/system/node/node*/meminfo  | egrep -i "huge"
Node 0 AnonHugePages:   1077248 kB
Node 0 HugePages_Total:     8
Node 0 HugePages_Free:      3
Node 0 HugePages_Surp:      0
Node 1 AnonHugePages:   1232896 kB
Node 1 HugePages_Total:     8
Node 1 HugePages_Free:      4
Node 1 HugePages_Surp:      0
Node 2 AnonHugePages:   1562624 kB
Node 2 HugePages_Total:     8
Node 2 HugePages_Free:      8
Node 2 HugePages_Surp:      0
Node 3 AnonHugePages:   1357824 kB
Node 3 HugePages_Total:     8
Node 3 HugePages_Free:      8
Node 3 HugePages_Surp:      0
#

Comment: ]#  cat /sys/devices/system/node/node*/meminfo  | egrep -i "mem"
Node 0 MemTotal:       33214844 kB
Node 0 MemFree:        17508240 kB
Node 0 MemUsed:        15706604 kB
Node 0 Shmem:               844 kB
Node 1 MemTotal:       33554432 kB
Node 1 MemFree:        11625680 kB
Node 1 MemUsed:        21928752 kB
Node 1 Shmem:             10124 kB
Node 2 MemTotal:       33554432 kB
Node 2 MemFree:          731552 kB
Node 2 MemUsed:        32822880 kB
Node 3 MemTotal:       33554428 kB
Node 3 MemFree:         6980368 kB
Node 3 MemUsed:        26574060 kB

Comment: did you try passing dpdk-ovs options as `-m 2048` or '--socket-limit=2048,1'

Comment: other_config        : {dpdk-hugepage-dir="/dev/hugepages", dpdk-init="true", dpdk-socket-mem="1024"} Already this option is given

Comment: `socket-mem` is the minimum guarentee from 18.11 onwards. It is not the maximum limit. Hence I humbly request for custom OVS-DPDK with 18.11 and above please use `socket-limit`

Comment: hi...how to change from native ovs networking to ovs-dpdk, is it just change configurtn file?.Currently my openstack packstack running as a single host. Please advise further. Thanks

Comment: @chenol one would require the binary or rpm package which has OVS built with DPDK. First checklist is see if one has the right binary, if yes then start the OVS-DPDK